# Не работает заполнение таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, for, table

Фрагмент кода:

```
<table id="tbl"></table>
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tbl.innerHTML += "<tr>";
        for(var j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            tbl.innerHTML += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
        tbl.innerHTML += "</tr>";
}
</script>
```

Таблицу заполняет так:

```
<tr></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>...
```

А должен так:

```
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
...
</tr>...
```

Comment: а что с того, что он где-то в невидимой для всех части отображает html в строку? или я что-то не понял?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, он должен в одну tr класть 50 td, а кладет 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не добавляйте незаконченный html в таблицу. Браузер сам закрывает незакрытый `tr`.

```
var rows = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    rows += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < 50; j++){
        rows += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    rows += "</tr>";
}
tbl.innerHTML = rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

В чём была ваша ошибка, уже подсказал @Igor, а я просто дам альтернативный вариант:

```
tbl.innerHTML = `<tr>${`<td>&nbsp;</td>`.repeat(50)}</tr>`.repeat(10);
```

Comment: А что это за запись такая? Ни разу не видел

Comment: @Nikita, [Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)